# How to query data from two databases and group results by range

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Exercise:

I have a table, called WEATHER, that records the temperature of cities which is formatted as follows:

[image: Table 1]

I also have an additional table that includes more information on
each city; The schema of `CITY` table is as follows:

[image: table 2]

I'm trying to write a query that queries both the `WEATHER` and `CITY` tables and outputs the
following:

The maximum temperature for each country, grouped by city population classified as:

- Small cities: Population size less than 1 million
- Medium cities: Population between 1 million and 5 million
- Large cities: Population greater than 5 million

I have searched for ways and examples on how to create alias and how the CASE statement works on SQL but I'm struggling to get the desired output.

This is where I managed to get:

```
SELECT
    CITY.Country,
    WEATHER.AVG(Maximum_Temperature) as Max_Temp,
    case CITY.Population
        when < 1000000 then "Small"
        when > 5000000 then "Large"
        else "Medium"
FROM
    CITY
INNER JOIN
    WEATHER
ON
    WEATHER.City_Name = CITY.City_Name
GROUP BY 
    CITY.Country
```

The output should look like:

[image: output table]

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, you don't really have a table. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax for what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT C.Country, AVG(W.Maximum_Temperature) as Max_Temp,
        (case when c.Population < 1000000 then 'Small'
              when c.Population > 5000000 then 'Large'
              else 'Medium'
         end)
FROM CITY C INNER JOIN
     WEATHER W
     ON W.City_Name = C.City_Name
GROUP BY C.Country,
         (case when c.Population < 1000000 then 'Small'
              when c.Population > 5000000 then 'Large'
              else 'Medium'
          end);
```

Note the changes:

- SQL uses single quotes to delimit strings, not double quotes (although some databases support extended functionality).
- The syntax `WEATHER.AVG()` does not do what you expect.  In most databases, it would be looking for a user-defined function called `AVG()` in the `WEATHER` schema/database.
- You do want to qualify all column references.
- To help with that, I've added table aliases as abbreviations for the table names.
- The `case` expression needs to be in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try that,

```
SELECT
    CITY.Country Country,
    CASE 
        WHEN CITY.Population < 1000001 'Small'
        WHEN CITY.Population < 5000001 'Medium'
        ELSE 'Large'
    END City_Size,
    WEATHER.AVG(Maximum_Temperature) as Max_Temp
FROM
    CITY
INNER JOIN
    WEATHER
ON
    CITY.City_Name = WEATHER.City_Name
GROUP BY 
    CITY.Country
```